# How to increase thickness of pen/pencil drawing?

Tags: pencil, bold

I have a notes/drawing drawn with light and thin color pencil. How do I increase the thickness of the color pen or pencil handwriting or the drawing and make it heavy weight and bold? How do I make my handwriting look more like a picture? What do I do if I want to change the shape of my handwriting? For example, I have this picture,
[image: Parsec]
*Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parsec.jpg*

Comment: @Vikas Yes, I want to make it bold, I don't want to change the colour darkness, I just want to change the thickness. And yes, this is my actual notes reference, it is my own work, I have uploaded it myself to Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what software, if any, you are using or plan to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in GIMP (which is free and open source)

Open the image and do *Filters > Distorts > Value Propagate*. Set the mode to "More black (smaller value)", then set the slider values as shown below. Adjust the thickness as desired by moving the propagating rate slider. You can also increase the Lower Threshold slider if the result is a bit blurry.

Here's the split view so you can see before and after

[image]

Note: If you feel this has gone a little too dark, it's also possible to use *Colors > Curves* to lighten it back up again, just a touch.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using **Adobe Photoshop**...

Choose `Filter > Other > Minimum...` from the menu and adjust to your liking...

[image]

Then a minor **Levels** (`Image > Adjustments > Levels`) adjustment to remove some "scum" coloring that exists around the type....

[image]

Result...

[image]

---

You **can** make specific selections in areas and run the filter to refine things in a more direct manner. There are a couple dashed lines on the left which get fairly lost in the above. (I may have lost them with too great a Levels adjustment) So *deselecting* those areas may be helpful. Or selecting them specifically for a greater filter value, before adjusting Levels may help.